# How is the Nokker in Hayase's successors passed through?

Tags: to-your-eternity

All the descendants of Hayase inherit the Nokker she had in her arm. But how does this happen? Is the Nokker passed to the child when the child is conceived? (and therefore the mother would lose the Nokker at that point?) Is it replicated? Is it passed when they get children get older or something?

How is the Nokker in Hayase's successors passed through?

Comment: The Wikipedia article says the Nokker is not even known to be the same [カハクの左腕に寄生しているノッカー。ハヤセ、ヒサメ、ウシオなどに寄生していたものと同一の固体かは不明。](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E6%BB%85%E3%81%AE%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%B8).

Comment: So I suppose it is not described in the story, but it should be kind of cut and paste (if it is the same) because there are obvious influences of [Parasyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasyte).